# Get files from directory's FileDescriptor

Tags: android, file-descriptor, android-file, android-contentresolver, android-fileprovider

I have content uri of directory from other app's share intent. From this I can create FileDescriptor and open InputStream. But how can I check if it's directory and get files if it's directory?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have content uri of directory from other app's share intent

There is no such thing as "content uri of directory", any more than there is a "REST URL of directory".

In certain cases, we may have a protocol where a `Uri` represents a collection of content (e.g., `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`, a `Uri` retrieved via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`). There is no such protocol for "content uri of directory", delivered via `ACTION_SEND`, in standard Android.

> From this I can create FileDescriptor and open InputStream

Possibly. That depends entirely upon what the `Uri` actually represents.

> But how can I check if it's directory and get files if it's directory?

In general, you can't.

If this `Uri` happens to be backed by a document provider, and the `Uri` happens to   represent a tree of content, `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` will let you list the documents in that tree, akin to the API on `File`.

Otherwise, you are welcome to look at the MIME type of the `Uri`. If the MIME type starts with `vnd.android.cursor.dir/`, then it should be a `Uri` that you can `query()`, though there are no rules for what columns there are. If the MIME type is anything else, there are no rules for what the content is and how you can use it.

For specific apps, you can contact the developers of the app and ask them "hey, when you give me a `Uri` that looks like this, how can I use it?".

TL;DR: if you are given a `Uri` via `ACTION_SEND`, where that `Uri` points to anything that is not a piece of content, the sending app has a bug.